# Age + "years old"

Tags: phrases, history

If I say "*She is seventeen*", is it as correct as "*She is seventeen year old*"?

I know it's correct, because it's used, but are both as correct or the first one is only tolerated?

When did this structure appeared in English? *Relatively* recently?

I guess y.o is only an abbreviation, and won't be considered as correct.

Comment: No - *She is seventeen year old* is ***not*** correct. Valid alternatives are *She is **a** seventeen year old* or *She is seventeen **years** old*. Note that in the first of those, the noun phrase would normally be hyphenated as *seventeen-year-old*, but that's just orthography, not real "grammar".

Comment: @Fumble - I had the same concern. The O.P.'s title says "years old", but the example says "year old". I'm wondering if that's just a typo.

Comment: Typo from someone who don't speak English as her first language.

Comment: @J.R.: I didn't notice that, but *I guess **y.o** is only an abbreviation* didn't exactly endear me to the question, so I can't be bothered to look for an earlier duplicate (which I've no doubt will exist).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"She is seventeen" and "She is seventeen years old" are both equivalent ways of saying that she is seventeen years of age - note the "s" after years. In regards the first expression, the fact that it refers to age is implied and commonly accepted.

I would not say that that the first one is merely "tolerated" - that's a bit of a strange word to use there. I would say that it is more informal than the second one.

I don't know when this structure - assuming you mean the first - appeared, but it is definitely still used today, if that's your concern.

y.o. is definitely an abbreviation, and one that I have never seen or heard before, until I read your question. So, it's not something used by native speakers.

Answer (score 5):

In general with times and ages, if a number clearly indicates what it is counting, it is not necessary to include that information.

If I say *she was just seventeen, you know what I mean* (from "I saw her standing there" by The Beatles) it is very clear I mean her age, in years. It is unlike I mean her weight in kilo's or stones or her height in meters or feet.

In the same way, you can leave out "o'clock" and the likes when you say *I got up at three this morning*. Obviously that means oh-three-hundred hours, 03:00h AM or three o'clock in the morning.